# Throw statement with no arguments, outside catch block in a common exception handler

Tags: c#, exception

I have a common exception handler function:

```
public static void ManageException(Exception ex,
                                   string customErrorMsg,
                                   bool displayMessage)
```

which I want to call from some of the catch blocks.

After processing the exception, I want to rethrow the exception, while preserving the stack trace.

I read somewhere that I should `throw` statement without any parameters. The `throw` statement (without any params) works fine in a `catch` block, but in my `ManageException` function, it gives me a compile error:

> A throw statement with no arguments is not allowed outside of a catch clause

Is there any solution to re-throw the exception with the whole stack trace and without any performance impact, from the `ManageException` function?

I am using C# 2.0.

Comment: You should do exactly what the compiler is telling you.  Call ManageException on your exception, and then throw it from the catch block.

Comment: But sometimes the ManageException will convert the exception to some other type and throw, whereas at other times, it will throw the original exception. If I put that code in catch block, I will have to paste the same 5-10 lines of code in every catch block, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the exception to throw, as in:

```
throw ex;
```

As stated in your error, you can only re-throw exceptions (with `throw;`) from inside a catch block. IMHO this is really the only place it makes sense to do so as well; you are either catching the exception, or throwing it, and probably should not do both. From a method called `ManageException`, I wonder why you would be managing said exception, but throwing it anyway.

*Perhaps you instead want to wrap the original exception in one of your own, providing additional details?* In this case I would throw a new exception with `ex` as the `InnerException`, if you want to preserve that data.

---

From your comment, if what you are trying to do is determine whether you should re-throw an exception or not, I would suggest:

- Rename your method to `TryManageException` and change the signature to return a `bool` - return a false if the exception was not managed properly and needs to be re-thrown; return a true if it was handled.
- If the method returns a false (= not managed), re-throw from the catch block or do whatever else you need:

  ```
  try
  {
      decimal oops = 5 / 0;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      if (!CommonExceptionHandler.TryManageException(e, "oops", "oops"))
          throw;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 8):

If you really need to re-throw an exception outside the catch block, you can use the following method:

```
ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception).Throw();
```

The [ExceptionDispatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.aspx) class is available since .NET Framework 4.5.

Usually, you shouldn't need to use this method; instead, you can a) re-throw the exception using the `throw;` command inside the catch block, or b) wrap the exception in another exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

A. Throw in catch block:

```
try
{
    //do stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ManageException(ex);
    throw;
}
```

B. Rethrow in handler method:

```
private void ManageException(Exception ex)
{
    //log or whatever
    throw new Exception("See inner exception", ex);
}
```

C. Handle on a higher level:
    For instance in ASP.NET use the Application_Error event handler method in Global.asax.
    All unhandled exceptions end up and can be handled there.

Answer (score 0):

You can only re-throw from inside of a catch block.  Think about it; if you're not in a catch block then your program just crashed or the exception was caught at a higher level.  It makes no sense to re-throw from outside a catch block.

Wrap your function in a try/catch and re-throw from the catch if needed.  Additionally, if *all you are doing* is re-throwing then there is no point; just let the exception bubble up.

Comment: Before I let the exception bubble up, I have to do some common steps, which I don't want to replicate in every try catch block, so I want to call the common function from the catch block. Depending on some conditions, I want to re-throw the exception with the full stack trace.

Comment: @AllSolutions, you can call `ManageException` from All `catch` blocks, to call common functions on `Exception ex` and re-throw in the original `catch` block itself.

Comment: @AllSolutions: Yep, just as Tilak said.  Putting your common error logic into a function is a good idea for obvious reasons.  However, you don't need to encapsulate `throw`. It will never change, just write that line after `ManageException(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> A throw statement can be used in the catch block to re-throw the exception, which has been caught by the catch statement.

If you want to preserve the stacktrace, you have to wrap it in [`InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx)

```
public static void ManageException(Exception ex, string customErrorMsg, bool displayMessage)
{
   ...
   throw new Exception ("Re-throwing", ex); // You can use your custom Exception object with custom message.
}
```

Caller of the `ManageException` should handle `ex.InnerException` instead of `ex`.

Comment: what do you mean "equivalent (not same)"? The latter one will change the stack trace associated with the exception.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, I was incorrect. Updated the answer accordingly.